# problems to dual boot between ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

When i click the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows 7 my system restarts and the dvd from which i am installing Trusty Tahr is ejected and then everything is to be started from the beginning.

I have used Ubuntu previously but i have never made a dual boot between Ubuntu and windows please help me to get rid of this issue

I have followed these steps but they didn't work: [How to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86KHkeBpsbA)

Comment: Look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370 and don't forget to make a backup before you change any partition. If you want to use hibernate, the swap size should be at least the ram size.

Comment: but would it be safe because i clearly remember last time i did the same thing to partition the hard drive and eventually lost everything

Comment: Absolutely save is nothing, you can make a backup of the whole disc for example with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to an external drive. That allows you to restore everything including the partition table and the MBR.

Comment: i have four partitions in my hard disk is that the problem which is preventing me to install ubuntu and windows alongside each other

Comment: Did you try the manual partitioning ?

Comment: no i have just clicked the option of install ubuntu alongside windows

Comment: but whatdoes manual partitioning mean

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation